# How to pass jQuery triggered event to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I am trying to test some javascript code (BackBone View) using jasmine

Here is the function within the defined BackBone view I am trying to test:

```
var aView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
       'click #btn': 'update'
        } 

update: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    ....
    });
}

});
```

So, to test the function I am trying to call the function and then spyOn $.ajax to see if it was called with appropriate url. 
But, the problem is I cannot pass the event into the function so that it carries out the ajax.

Here's the jasmine code block:

```
it("tests update ajax", function() {

             spyOn($, "ajax");

             //Call update function
            this.aView.update(this.aView.$("#btn").trigger("click"));

            expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

Here's the error I am currently receiving:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'preventDefault'
```

I hope I have provided all the information necessary and the question is precise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call the update method directly. It will work, if you trigger the event, that will call the update method.

The following should remove your current error:

```
it("tests update ajax", function() {

        this.aView.$el.find('.update').trigger("update");
        this.aView.update(this.aView.$("#btn").trigger("click"));

});
```

if your view has this:

```
var aView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    'click a.update' : 'update'
  },

  update: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      ....
    });
  }
});
```

With that you check also if your view events are set correctly.

Comment: In the view the event is declared as `{'click #btn': 'update'}` so i am trying to pass in that event to the update function... this sounds wrong, am i missing something?

Comment: Update: thanks! got it instead of calling the event in the function I just had to trigger the click and the function would be called. I thought I tried that... oh well works now :).. so had to change the code inside to just                 `this.detailsView.$('#btnSave').trigger("click");`